# How to select all children in subparents apart from first

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This should be a simple thing but I can't seem to find what I'm after. I've got a parent div with sub-parents and children inside.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="subparent1">
    <div class="foo">foo1 </div>
    <div class="bar">bar1 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subparent2"> 
    <div class="foo">foo2 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subparent3">
    <div class="bar">bar2 </div>
    <div class="foo">foo3 </div>
    <div class="bar">bar3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide all '.foo' classes apart from the first one. How do I use CSS3 to select all the rest of '.foo' apart from the first?

PS -- number of '.foo' is dynamic and will change.

Comment: `.parent .foo {display:none;}` and `.parent .foo:first {display:block;}` ?

Comment: @mshsayem: There is no `:first` in CSS.

Comment: oh i see; in that case: `.parent > .foo {display:none;}` and
`.parent>.foo:first-of-type {display:block;}` ?

Comment: @mshsayem: That will indeed work, but BoltClock's solution is much simpler and will also work in nasty old browsers like IE7/8. Your idea will result in all `.foo` being hidden in browsers that don't support CSS3 selectors.

Comment: @thirtydot: That won't work as intended in modern browsers anyway - `:first-of-type` doesn't mean first of class. You probably already know this, but for other readers, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) for an explanation.

Comment: @BoltClock: It did "work" due to `.foo` being the first `div` anyway, but yeah. I'm bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A situation like this depends on prior knowledge of the HTML structure; there's no way to do it using CSS alone without having predictable HTML, because CSS doesn't have the ability to select the first grandchild of a certain kind, only the first *child*.

For example, if you know that the first `.foo` will *always* occur in the first subparent, you may be able to get away with selecting any `.foo` to display as a block, then selecting all subsequent subparents and `.foo`s using the [general sibling combinator `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) and hiding them:

```css
.parent > .subparent1 > .foo {
    display: block;
}

.parent > .subparent1 > .foo ~ .foo, /* .foo after the first in .subparent1 */
.parent > .subparent1 ~ div > .foo { /* .foo in subparents after .subparent1 */
    display: none;
}
```

If `.subparent1` may not contain any `.foo` elements at all, and you want to select the first very `.foo` regardless of its subparent, I don't think it's possible with CSS selectors alone. You may have to find a different way, e.g. by assigning an extra class to the first `.foo` since it's dynamically generated, or using JavaScript to apply styles instead.

Comment: Thank you very much and that works, but now I have a different problem. What if the '.parent' class has subparents that contains '.foo'? http://jsfiddle.net/kucF5/

Comment: @user1775598: Do you want to hide all `.foo` except foo1? Perhaps you should edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: And I've edited my answer. Unfortunately your situation is much more complicated and may not always have a pure CSS solution. I've explained it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much - fortunately in this situation I know the name of the subparent which will always have the child in it. I tried your solution and it worked, thanks!